# jsplumb - scroll the canvas when node dragged outside visible area

Tags: javascript, css, jsplumb

I'm trying out jsplumb. I have a copy of this demo: https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/statemachine/index.html

In this demo, when I drag one of the nodes outside of the canvas boundary, a scrollbar appears to indicate the canvas area has expanded. However, I still have to manually scroll the view to see the dragged node.

I would like the view to automatically scroll when I drag a node beyond the edge. Same thing when dragging a new connector, I would like to automatically scroll the view - so I can choose to connect to a node currently outside the visible area. Any advice on how to do this?

Secondary question: In the demo above the scrollbars appear as expected when I drag elements off the right or bottom of the canvas, but not when I drag them off the left edge or off the top edge. That is, if I drag a node upward off the canvas and drop it there, I no longer have any way of viewing that node or dragging it back down. Is there a way around this?